# How can I get standardized factor loadings with the semopy package in python?

Tags: python, factor-analysis

I'm using the semopy python package to do confirmatory factor analysis, and have a couple of questions:

1. How do I get standardised factor loadings?
2. Is there a way to get modification indices (to help adapt the model step by step)?
3. How do I get the correlations between the factors?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a boolean argument *std_est* for the *inspect* method that adds a standardized estimates column to the returned DataFrame with parameters estimates.
2. See [Fit Indices](http://semopy.com/indices.html) at the semopy website
3. Do you mean that you seek to "standardize" covariances by latent factor variances? If so, you can use this code snippet:

> ```
> cov = model.inspect('mx')['Psi']
> stds = np.diagonal(cov) ** (-0.5)
> corr = std * cov * std
> ```

Comment: Thank you Jeor. Yes, sorry, I meant standardised covariances for no. 3. Thanks a lot for your answer. For this research finally I decided to use lavaan in R, everything seemed easier. But in the longer run, I would like to keep to python, so thanks for the answers.